# Name of the "left" set on which a partial function $f\colon \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to\mathbb N$ is defined

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Given a partial function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

Does the set:

$$A = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists y \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } f(x,y) \text { is defined}\}$$

have a name?

(sorry if the question is too trivial)

Comment: If pressed, I would call it the left projection of the domain of $f$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Off topic. You might be interested in answering [this](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/real-world-applications-of-logic).

Comment: @Git: I don't think I have the credentials to play there. I can easily think up an opinion about the subject, but it would be unbacked by any experience actually trying to teach it ...